# What permissions are needed in azure AD portal for getting user data via sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I wanted to use "_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties" this endpoint to fetch user details. While fetching data, I am getting below error message :

"value": "Access Denied: This application does not have the required permissions to access profile information."

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a solution, the SharePoint User.Read.All permissions can be used to fetch the User Profile properties using Azure AD with Certificate based authentication - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if that endpoint can be used to get user properties from Azure. It might be better to use Microsoft graph to achieve retrieving user properties if you are not working from within SharePoint directly.

If you are building your app with JavaScript you can use the package;
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/graph/users/#user-properties

Regarding the permissions required, refer to the article below, it describes how to setup your application on Azure and the necessary information you will use to connect to SharePoint via the App permissions you have configured on Azure.

The article describes how to read sites but, in your case, you will focus on assigning the app permission to read user info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread